# How to set dimension for long multi-plot figure in patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I am learning R and I would like to produce a long yet readable image of 11 plots (one column) using the patchwork package in R. However, because this are so many plots, the output image gets distorted/ squished and is unreadable. Here is my reprex:

```
data(diamonds)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

a <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = clarity)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
b <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = color)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
c <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = table)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
d <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = cut)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
e <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = x)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
f <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = depth)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
g <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = carat)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")
h <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(y = z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count", orientation = "y")

a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h +
  plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

This is the image produced:
[image]

How can I lock the aspect so that it is readable and even scrollable in MS Word, if this is possible?

Please let me know if I can provide more information or need to use a different package. Ultimately I will export this figure as a .png to Microsoft Word. Thank you.

Comment: You will want to add `theme(aspect.ratio)` to each of the plots. Given what you are doing, it may be better to reshape the data and use `facet_wrap` rather than combining the plots (but you lose the ordering of the factor variables).

Comment: Thanks @mikebader for the quick reply! Would you mind explaining why facet_wrap would be better? Unfortunately I do need to control the ordering of my factor variables, but I will look into theme(aspect.ratio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are running into two problems:

1. The plot size of the device
2. The aspect ratio of the plots themselves

The first will be determined by the size of the device R plots to. The plots will attempt to fill the entire device. If you set the device so that it has more vertical than horizontal space, the plots will self-adjust. The problem is that you are trying to include a lot of plots on a single device. For a single piece of paper, it will be difficult to read all of them.

The other issue tells `ggplot` how you want each graph displayed. In this case, the aspect ratio between x- and y- will be set regardless of the area included in the device.

Below, I solve the first problem by breaking the columns of `diamonds` into two sets of five. I then save a PNG image for each, setting the size of the PNG to letter paper with 1-inch margins. I solve the second problem by setting `theme(aspect.ratio = 1)` to ensure a series of square plots (you can play with this to create different aspect ratios).

I wrap the whole thing in a function using the "don't repeat yourself" (DRY) principle of programming.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

bplt <- function(yvar) {
    ggplot(diamonds, aes_(y = as.name(yvar))) + geom_bar() +
        theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
}
wrap_plots(lapply(names(diamonds)[1:5], bplt), ncol = 1)
ggsave("~/tmp/diamond_features1.png", width = 6.5, height = 9, units = "in")
wrap_plots(lapply(names(diamonds)[6:10], bplt), ncol = 1)
ggsave("~/tmp/diamond_features2.png", width = 6.5, height = 9, units = "in")
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. It's incredibly helpful and I really appreciate it! I will follow-up with any questions in the comments if I hit any snags.